# Intensifying a light source using black body concept

Tags: optics, thermal-radiation

Is it possible to intensify light by initially passing it through an apparatus like a perfectly black body and then through a colloidal solution?
What kind of material can be used inside the assemblyso that the light gets multiple reflections before it is ejected out?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "intensify light". Are you trying to focus it? Also, do you mean the black body would be the source of the light? You can't pass light through a black body as your question currently suggests, as a black body absorbs all light incident upon it.

Comment: You can't pass light thru a black body, by definition.  Your question makes no sense.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "intensify" ?   Words like that (and "brightness") have highly specific technical meanings; and if you misuse them; you mis-communicate ideas.

But for starters; it is well known that the "radiance" or "luminance" of a radiation /light source is invariant under all optical transformations.   So you cannot increase the radiance of a source (Watt's per steradian per square meter) by optical means, and by inference (bi-directionality), you cannot decrease it either (by optical means; only by absorption).

Some little impediment called the second law of thermo-dynamics prohibits that.

So the answer to your question is "no" ;   or "hell no"

Comment: The radiance would be simply Watts per steradian, not Watts per steradian per square meter.